# Use Python Selenium cookies and Requests to download PDF from pdf viewer

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, python-requests

Im familiar with Selenium, new to Requests. There is this webpage that contains public PDFs, but you have to navigate to each of them. So what I would want is to navigate to that url with Selenium, then use the cookies in requests to download the PDF.

I'm gonna then upload this solution to AWS lambda, so clicking the download button is not an option (nor is using - "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True - in chrome options).
Here is what I tried so far:

I follow the below instructions and navigate to the PDF with selenium (wont include code because it's long and simple but I can confirm I'm in the PDF viewer page), and then:

```
url = driver.current_url
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
s = requests.Session()
for cookie in cookies:
    if 'httpOnly' in cookie:
        httpO = cookie.pop('httpOnly')
        cookie['rest'] = {'httpOnly': httpO}
    if 'expiry' in cookie:
        cookie['expires'] = cookie.pop('expiry')
    s.cookies.set(**cookie)
filename = Path('myPDF.pdf')
response = s.get(url)
filename2.write_bytes(response.content)
print(response)
OUT: <Response [404]>
print(cookies)
OUT: [{'domain': '.pjud.cl', 'expiry': 1677609957, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '_ga', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': 'GA1.2.184425928.1614537957'}, {'domain': '.pjud.cl', 'expiry': 1614624357, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '_gid', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': 'GA1.2.739803934.1614537957'}, {'domain': '.oficinajudicialvirtual.pjud.cl', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'TS01262d1d', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': '01b485afe5b672a4e38a46b7a3a68bf7abce5fe06744257fa0f994999756bd24588a29453de9650e8fdfe73a401e5d854fe3c382a3b4a0677cbbe7d18acd3bc46c00faebd1'}, {'domain': '.pjud.cl', 'expiry': 1614538017, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '_gat_gtag_UA_63880126_1', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': '1'}, {'domain': 'oficinajudicialvirtual.pjud.cl', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'PHPSESSID', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': '6f9a7ee252846eeb63a6cc2233dacf21'}]
print(s.cookies)
OUT: <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie TS01262d1d=01b485afe5b672a4e38a46b7a3a68bf7abce5fe06744257fa0f994999756bd24588a29453de9650e8fdfe73a401e5d854fe3c382a3b4a0677cbbe7d18acd3bc46c00faebd1 for .oficinajudicialvirtual.pjud.cl/>, <Cookie _ga=GA1.2.184425928.1614537957 for .pjud.cl/>, <Cookie _gat_gtag_UA_63880126_1=1 for .pjud.cl/>, <Cookie _gid=GA1.2.739803934.1614537957 for .pjud.cl/>, <Cookie PHPSESSID=6f9a7ee252846eeb63a6cc2233dacf21 for oficinajudicialvirtual.pjud.cl/>]>
```

[Here's an example of a url.](https://oficinajudicialvirtual.pjud.cl/ADIR_871/civil/documentos/docu.php?valorEncTxtDmda=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvb2ZpY2luYWp1ZGljaWFsdmlydHVhbC5wanVkLmNsIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL29maWNpbmFqdWRpY2lhbHZpcnR1YWwucGp1ZC5jbCIsImlhdCI6MTYxNDUzNzgwOCwiZXhwIjoxNjE0NTQxNDA4LCJkYXRhIjp7ImNycl9pZGRvY3VtZW50IjoiNzA0ODI1MSIsImNvZGlfdHJpYnVuYWwiOiIyNTkiLCJlbnRpcGFyY2hpdm8iOiIzIn19.Wn5iuVt8OWVAoj1KgAKFuZqgsFAV4qSSNrplfTPxvJM)

It will tell you that session has expired, but you can follow the instructions below to get to one.
Note that its a pdf viewer, and it does not end in .pdf (don't know if that makes a difference)

To get to one you have to:

1. go into https://oficinajudicialvirtual.pjud.cl/home/index.php
2. hover over "Otros Servicios"
3. click on "Consulta de Causas"
4. In "Competencia" (drop down menu) put Corte Apelacions
5. in "Corte" (drop down menu), put CA Santiago
6. in "Año" input 2019
7. in "Libro/Tipo"(drop down menu), put Civil
8. in "Rol" input 2522 (all these are the ones I want to scrape)
9. Click "Buscar"
10. only 1 result appears, click the magnifying glass on the left
11. popup with details comes up, click on "Expediente Primera Instancia"
12. click on the magnifying glass next to "Causa Origen"
13. click on the file icon below "Texto/demanda". The pdf is opened in a pdf viewer in a new tab.

The PDF created is empty, and the response returns <Response [404]>. Help?
Do I need to add headers to the request? I don't know how to do that.Thanks!